# Can I upgrade from Visual Studio 2012 (11) RC to Final / RTM?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rc, rtm

I have noticed that there are a lot of improvements in Visual Studio 11 when it comes to the designer, and I really want to switch to 2012 as fast as possible.

The question is - if I download the Release Candidate now, can I then just "reinstall" or upgrade to the RTM/final version when that is out, or do I need to uninstall and mess about?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626077/upgrading-visual-studio-2010-rc-to-rtm-retail-final) question, regarding VS 2010, and its answer says that you need to uninstall everything, but when it comes to 2012 I read that upgrading from BETA to RC is just an install, no need to uninstall.

I have tried searching for an answer, but to no avail.

Comment: But how does one upgrade? I ran the VS 2012 Ultimate RTM setup on a matchine that has a VS 2012 Ultimate RC and it feels like it is about to do a fresh install. No upgrade option is showing up.

Comment: @Maxim V. Pavlov: Yeah, it doesn't make it clear that it's upgrading, but it actually is. The RC components will all be replaced with their RTM builds. (At least if you install in the same directory as the RC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh darn it, I got it to work.

Just found the answer, I think "Supported: Upgrade from Visual Studio 2012 Release Candidate to Release (RTM) (same edition only - e.g., Professional RC to Professional RTM)" (microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/compatibility)